# Styled components media query mixin seems to ignore props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I created a media query that looks like this:

`media.ts`

```
export const breakpoints = {
  sm: 420,
  md: 768,
  lg: 992,
  xlg: 1200,
};

export const media = Object.keys(breakpoints).reduce((acc, label) => {
  acc[label] = (literals: TemplateStringsArray, ...placeholders: any[]) =>
    css`
      @media (min-width: ${breakpoints[label]}px) {
        ${css(literals, ...placeholders)};
      }
    `.join('');
  return acc;
}, {} as Record<keyof typeof breakpoints, (l: TemplateStringsArray, ...p: any[]) => string>);
```

Which will work like this:

```
 * @example
 * const StyledComponent = styled.div`
 *  background-color: red;
 *
 *  ${media.sm`
 *    background-color: blue
 *  `}
 *
 *  ${media.md`
 *    background-color: green;
 *  `}
```

However, when I pass props into the media query, it seems to get ignored. Example here:

```
<GreetingContainer isTesting>
...
</GreetingContainer>

const GreetingContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  background: green;

  ${media.md`
    flex-direction: row;
  `}

  ${media.lg`
    background: ${(props: { isTesting: any }) => (props.isTesting ? 'blue' : 'red')};
  `}
` as any;
```

It seems like in my `media.lg`, the whole thing gets ignored completely. Does anyone know what's going on? Is there a workaround or a fix in the utility I've written?

I'm seeing my css looks like this:

[image]

which is very much not what I want. What seems to be the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is the ending `.join('')`, which forces the output of [`css`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css) template tag function to be converted as a *string*, hence the "inlining" of your function body in the CSS rule.

Just remove it to restore your expected behaviour:

```
export const media = Object.keys(breakpoints).reduce((acc, label) => {
  acc[label] = (literals: TemplateStringsArray, ...placeholders: any[]) =>
    css`
      @media (min-width: ${breakpoints[label]}px) {
        ${css(literals, ...placeholders)};
      }
    `; //.join(""); // Let the output remain a function
  return acc;
}, {} as Record<keyof typeof breakpoints, (l: TemplateStringsArray, ...p: any[]) => string>);
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-benji-qepx9o?file=/src/App.tsx